# How to achive this timeline look only using html and css maybe some bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, timeline

[image]

So far i only can achieve to this point. I am using example code from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp)

[image]

I trying to figure out to get year in the same position like in the picture but no luck and also tried to insert image background for circle but only manage to color fill

```css
/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */

.timeline::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #ffc200;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}


/* Container around content */

.contaiment {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}


/* The circles on the timeline */

.contaiment::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -11px;
  background-color: #ffc200;
  border: 4px solid #ffc200;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Place the container to the left */

.left {
  left: 0;
}


/* Place the container to the right */

.right {
  left: 50%;
}


/* Add arrows to the left container (pointing right) */


/* .left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
} */


/* Add arrows to the right container (pointing left) */

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}


/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */

.right::after {
  left: -16px;
}


/* The actual content */

.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="contaiment left">
    <div class="content">
      <p>2017
        <p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contaiment right">
    <div class="content">
      <p class="">2017
        <p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contaiment left">
    <div class="content">
      <p class="">2017
        <p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have some errors in your html. Check your code with a validator. For example check your <p> tag, you have nested it

Comment: already fix that doesn't really affect anything , what i really want really is year beside left or right circle not inside the white box

Comment: Please show what you have tried - e.g. to get the background image in the yellow circle or to get the year and the text separated. Though personally, I'd start again, ditching that code (which is not responsive) and looking into for example a 2 or 3 column grid.

Comment: oh yeah column grid good idea

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to do something with only HTML and CSS, but take a look at this JQuery library. It's very easy to use.
https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections/wiki/API

You just need to set the 2 elements you want to connect.

```
$("#div1, #div2").connections();
$("#div2, #div3").connections();
$("#div3, #div4").connections();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p style="width: 50px;height: 50px;border: 1px solid black;" id="div1">TEST</p>
        <p style="width: 50px;height: 50px;margin-left: 50px;border: 1px solid black;" id="div2">TEST</p>
        <p style="width: 50px;height: 50px;margin-left: 200px;border: 1px solid black;" id="div3">TEST</p>
        <p style="width: 50px;height: 50px;margin-left: 300px;border: 1px solid black;" id="div4">TEST</p>

        <!-- Script retrieved from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections/gh-pages/jquery.connections.js -->
    <script>
      (function($) {
  $.fn.connections = function(options) {
    if (options === "update") {
      return processConnections(update, this);
    } else if (options === "remove") {
      return processConnections(destroy, this);
    } else {
      options = $.extend(
        true,
        {
          borderClasses: {},
          class: "connection",
          css: {},
          from: this,
          tag: "connection",
          to: this,
          within: ":root"
        },
        options
      );
      connect(options);
      return this;
    }
  };

  $.event.special.connections = {
    teardown: function(namespaces) {
      processConnections(destroy, $(this));
    }
  };

  var connect = function(options) {
    var borderClasses = options.borderClasses;
    var tag = options.tag;
    var end1 = $(options.from);
    var end2 = $(options.to);
    var within = $(options.within);
    delete options.borderClasses;
    delete options.tag;
    delete options.from;
    delete options.to;
    delete options.within;
    within.each(function() {
      var container = this;
      var done = new Array();
      end1.each(function() {
        var node = this;
        done.push(this);
        end2.not(done).each(function() {
          createConnection(
            container,
            [node, this],
            tag,
            borderClasses,
            options
          );
        });
      });
    });
  };

  var createConnection = function(
    container,
    nodes,
    tag,
    borderClasses,
    options
  ) {
    var css = $.extend({ position: "absolute" }, options.css);
    var connection = $("<" + tag + "/>", options).css(css);
    connection.appendTo(container);

    var border_w = (connection.outerWidth() - connection.innerWidth()) / 2;
    var border_h = (connection.outerHeight() - connection.innerHeight()) / 2;

    if (border_w <= 0 && border_h <= 0) {
      border_w = border_h = 1;
    }

    var data = {
      borderClasses: borderClasses,
      border_h: border_h,
      border_w: border_w,
      node_from: $(nodes[0]),
      node_to: $(nodes[1]),
      nodes_dom: nodes,
      css: css
    };

    if ("none" === connection.css("border-top-style")) {
      data.css.borderStyle = "solid";
    }
    $.data(connection.get(0), "connection", data);
    $.data(connection.get(0), "connections", [connection.get(0)]);
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var connections = connection.add($.data(nodes[i], "connections")).get();
      $.data(nodes[i], "connections", connections);
      if (connections.length == 1) {
        $(nodes[i]).on("connections.connections", false);
      }
    }
    update(connection.get(0));
  };

  var destroy = function(connection) {
    var nodes = $.data(connection, "connection").nodes_dom;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var connections = $($.data(nodes[i], "connections"))
        .not(connection)
        .get();
      $.data(nodes[i], "connections", connections);
    }
    $(connection).remove();
  };

  var getState = function(data) {
    data.rect_from = data.nodes_dom[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    data.rect_to = data.nodes_dom[1].getBoundingClientRect();
    var cached = data.cache;
    data.cache = [
      data.rect_from.top,
      data.rect_from.right,
      data.rect_from.bottom,
      data.rect_from.left,
      data.rect_to.top,
      data.rect_to.right,
      data.rect_to.bottom,
      data.rect_to.left
    ];
    data.hidden =
      0 === (data.cache[0] | data.cache[1] | data.cache[2] | data.cache[3]) ||
      0 === (data.cache[4] | data.cache[5] | data.cache[6] | data.cache[7]);
    data.unmodified = true;
    if (cached === undefined) {
      return (data.unmodified = false);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      if (cached[i] !== data.cache[i]) {
        return (data.unmodified = false);
      }
    }
  };

  var update = function(connection) {
    var data = $.data(connection, "connection");
    getState(data);
    if (data.unmodified) {
      return;
    }
    var border_h = data.border_h;
    var border_w = data.border_w;
    var from = data.rect_from;
    var to = data.rect_to;
    var b = (from.bottom + from.top) / 2;
    var r = (to.left + to.right) / 2;
    var t = (to.bottom + to.top) / 2;
    var l = (from.left + from.right) / 2;

    var h = ["right", "left"];
    if (l > r) {
      h = ["left", "right"];
      var x = Math.max(r - border_w / 2, Math.min(from.right, to.right));
      r = l + border_w / 2;
      l = x;
    } else {
      l -= border_w / 2;
      r = Math.min(r + border_w / 2, Math.max(from.left, to.left));
    }
    var v = ["bottom", "top"];
    if (t > b) {
      v = ["top", "bottom"];
      var x = Math.max(b - border_h / 2, Math.min(from.bottom, to.bottom));
      b = t + border_h / 2;
      t = x;
    } else {
      b = Math.min(b, Math.max(from.top, to.top));
      t -= border_h / 2;
    }
    var width = r - l;
    var height = b - t;
    if (width < border_w) {
      t = Math.max(t, Math.min(from.bottom, to.bottom));
      b = Math.min(b, Math.max(from.top, to.top));
      l = Math.max(from.left, to.left);
      r = Math.min(from.right, to.right);
      r = l = (l + r - border_w) / 2;
    }
    if (height < border_h) {
      l = Math.max(l, Math.min(from.right, to.right));
      r = Math.min(r, Math.max(from.left, to.left));
      t = Math.max(from.top, to.top);
      b = Math.min(from.bottom, to.bottom);
      b = t = (t + b - border_h) / 2;
    }
    width = r - l;
    height = b - t;
    width <= 0 && (border_h = 0);
    height <= 0 && (border_w = 0);
    var style =
      "border-" +
      v[0] +
      "-" +
      h[0] +
      "-radius: 0;" +
      "border-" +
      v[0] +
      "-" +
      h[1] +
      "-radius: 0;" +
      "border-" +
      v[1] +
      "-" +
      h[0] +
      "-radius: 0;";
    (border_h <= 0 || border_w <= 0) &&
      (style += "border-" + v[1] + "-" + h[1] + "-radius: 0;");
    if (data.hidden) {
      style += "display: none;";
    } else {
      data.css["border-" + v[0] + "-width"] = 0;
      data.css["border-" + h[0] + "-width"] = 0;
      data.css["border-" + v[1] + "-width"] = border_h;
      data.css["border-" + h[1] + "-width"] = border_w;
      var current_rect = connection.getBoundingClientRect();
      data.css.left = connection.offsetLeft + l - current_rect.left;
      data.css.top = connection.offsetTop + t - current_rect.top;
      data.css.width = width - border_w;
      data.css.height = height - border_h;
    }
    var bc = data.borderClasses;
    $(connection)
      .removeClass(bc[v[0]])
      .removeClass(bc[h[0]])
      .addClass(bc[v[1]])
      .addClass(bc[h[1]])
      .attr("style", style)
      .css(data.css);
  };

  var processConnections = function(method, elements) {
    return elements.each(function() {
      var connections = $.data(this, "connections");
      if (connections instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0, len = connections.length; i < len; i++) {
          method(connections[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
    </script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript">
            $("#div1, #div2").connections();
      $("#div2, #div3").connections();
      $("#div3, #div4").connections();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```